# Accessing Schedule Information through Foundry's API

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I am having trouble finding the correct endpoint to use to access schedule information in Palantir Foundry.  The documentation provides examples of how to access datasets, ontology objects, actions, and even files (all which I can successfully do).  However, I am lost in regards to accessing schedule information.

Ideally, I would like to be able to pull all schedules from a specified connection for analysis, including scheduled start times and typical run lengths.

I have tried using the RID for a single schedule in various iterations of the URLs used in the documentation (as well as calling without the RID to see if the varied endpoints exists).  Things like:

- [base url]/api/v1/ontologies/[a schedule RID]
- [base url]/api/v1/ontologies/[ontology RID]/[a schedule RID]
- [base url]/api/v1/ontologies/[ontology RID]/schedules/[a schedule RID]
- [base url]/api/v1/ontologies/[ontology RID]/scheduler/[a schedule RID]
- [base url]/api/v1/ontologies/[ontology RID]/schedule/[a schedule RID]
- [base url]/api/v1/schedules/[a schedule RID]
- [base url]/api/v1/scheduler/[a schedule RID]
- [base url]/api/v1/schedule/[a schedule RID]

And even this URL from another question about the platform (and other variations on this):

- [base url]/job-tracker/api/builds/summary/

The last one was the only one to not provide a 404 response, but it did give a 400 response even when mirroring the provided answer exactly.

I was expecting a list of schedules in some capacity.  Even if it is just their RIDs and I have to look up the details one-by-one, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Teaching to fish instead of answering, but:

You can open the [Network Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network) in the Inspect console (in Chrome for instance) and look at the API call(s) executed to get/post information to a given website - the URL used, the payload, the response, ...

You could use this in your case to figure out what API call gets the information you want, by looking at a page that display the information you want or need.

Bear in mind that any API calls "reverse-engineered" and not in the public documentation is deemed "undocumented" and so might break without any warning, back-compatibility, newer alternative, etc. You do this at your own risks.